# Jenkins static code analysis for sbt project

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, findbugs, cpd

I have sbt project with findbugs4sbt, cpd4sbt plugins.
This project is builded by Jenkins with Static Code Analysis Plug-ins. 
I run "sbt findbugs" and "sbt cpd" build steps after compile and see target/findbugs/report.xml and target/cpd/cpd.xml files in Workspace, but I don`t see any reports in project.
How to configure Jenkins to show results of findbugs and cpd plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the filename of the XML report. By default, Jenkins look for the files "**findbugs.xml**" or "**findbugsXml.xml**".

In your Jenkins configuration, look for the "**Publish FindBugs analysis results**" section.

[image]